# Conversion of array to JSON doesn't handle nested array

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have a weird problem occurring when I convert a PHP array to JSON. If the array contains a nested array then the resulting JSON prints out `Array` instead of the contents of the array (for eg `{ 'foo': 1, 'bar': 2 }`.

```
  $result = [
      'type' => "success",
      'message' => "Shortcode successfully executed.",
      'content' => null
  ];
  $result['content'] = do_shortcode('[xyz]', false); // I have confirmed it returns an associative array of values

  // header('Content-type=> application/json');
  $result = json_encode($result); //, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
  echo $result;
  die();
```

The response is:

> {"type":"success","message":"Shortcode successfully executed.","content":"Array"}

It should be:

> {"type":"success","message":"Shortcode successfully executed.","content": { 'foo': 1, 'bar': 2 }}

Comment: Please `var_dump` in  your `do_shortcode`

Comment: what will be return from `do_shortcode` ?

Comment: Can you add the results of do_shortcode('[xyz]', false);

Comment: It seems your array is treated as a string, not as an array.

Comment: "do_shortcode" always return a string then you cannot use shortcode to work with array.

Comment: You should try $result = json_decode(json_encode($result));

Comment: I took the `do_shortcode` here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/ and try your code, this is hat I get : `{"type":"success","message":"Shortcode successfully executed.","content":"[xyz]"}` and as write in my previous link : `RETURN (string) Content with shortcodes filtered out.` so not an array